# Sublime Text 3 - Hitting tab doesn't add space, instead makes text lower case

Tags: tabs, sublimetext3, indentation, lowercase

If I were to type the following:

```
TEST
```

Then hit TAB, the code would now look like this:

```
test
```

I don't know what happened, but tab is not indenting anymore and changes the text on the current line to lowercase.

Any idea how to restore the TAB function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible reason for this in the general case is that you have installed a third party package that's stolen the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key binding in order to perform it's own action, which in this case would be turning the prior word lower case.

This will be the case if this behaviour holds true for any word that you happen to press <kbd>Tab</kbd> after. In that case the solution would be to find the package that's doing this and disable or reconfigure it.

In your case I think the more likely cause for this is that in the file you're currently editing the word `TEST` appears, and you have the following setting turned on:

```json
// When enabled, pressing tab will insert the best matching completion.
// When disabled, tab will only trigger snippets or insert a tab.
// Shift+tab can be used to insert an explicit tab when tab_completion is
// enabled.
"tab_completion": true,
```

When the setting is set to `true` (which is the default), pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> will attempt to perform a tab completion, which considers not only snippets and completions but also words in the current buffer as well.

In that case, if you were to enter the word `test` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> at a point where the word `TEST` also appears in the buffer, it's considered a potential completion and will become the replacement.

If this is the problem you would see similar behaviour by just entering `t` and pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>, which would cycle through all of the `T` words in the buffer as possible completions.

Assuming this is what's happening to you, one of the following should fix the problem for you:

1. Set `tab_completion` to `false` in your preferences; this will disable the feature entirely everywhere
2. Set `tab_completion` to `false` only in the settings of the specific file type that you're having the problem in; that would leave the feature enabled in the general case but stop it from occurring in the files that you don't want it to occur in.
3. Use <kbd>Shift+Tab</kbd> instead; that key sequence will do what <kbd>Tab</kbd> normally does and insert a tab character even if <kbd>Tab</kbd> would try to do a completion.

For #3 to work, make sure that you have this setting set as follows:

```json
// By default, shift+tab will only unindent if the selection spans
// multiple lines. When pressing shift+tab at other times, it'll insert a
// tab character - this allows tabs to be inserted when tab_completion is
// enabled. Set this to true to make shift+tab always unindent, instead of
// inserting tabs.
"shift_tab_unindent": false,
```

The default for this value is `false`, in which case as the comment mentions the binding will perform a tab unless you have multiple lines selected in which case it unindents instead.

Comment: Thanks, adding "tab_completion": false, to my preferences worked. For the record, I've never installed any additional third party packages. This issue just started happening today, perhaps I hit a shortcut key command by accident to cause this?

Comment: If changing the setting solved your problem, then it would have always done this but this is just the first time the right combination of existing words and desire for indenting right after one of them existed at the same time.